# How to create RPMs under Windows only by useing install free binaries or .net?

Tags: cygwin, package, rpm, rpmbuild

I am looking for a lightweight method to create rpm packages under MS Windows environments.
Actually I use Cygwin. I generate the rpm by using cmake(cpack). For cmake I need to install gcc to bypass the compiler check. For the rpm generation I have the rpm & rpm-build packages installed. When I am checking the size of the Cygwin dir it is around 2.2GByte. Quite a lot for generating a "simple" rpm.

Is there a "better" way to generate RPMs? Maybe in .net etc.?

Comment: why do you need an rpm for windows ?

Comment: to manage configuration for an embeeded system

Answer (score 1):

I know I'm a bit late to the party, but I've started the dotnet-packaging project, which allows you to create RPM and Debian packages on any platform that hosts .NET/.NET Core. So that includes Windows.

You can either use it as a library or as a .NET command-line utility (e.g. you could just run `dotnet rpm` on your project and it would create a RPM file for you).

https://github.com/qmfrederik/dotnet-packaging has the code and a getting started guide, let me know if that works.